# git hooks / pre-receive - how to get all the commit messages on a newly created branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, githooks

i' d like to get all the commit messages (like with git log --format=%s) on a newly created branch. Let' s suppose i' ve 2 commits:

```
abcd - from yesterday
bcde - from today
```

. With this code:

```
while read old new ref; do
    ....
done
```

old will be 40 zeros, and new will be bcde. How can i get all the commit messages in this case?

Usecase:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b new_branch
some_work
git add; git commit
some_other_work
git add; git commit
git push origin new_branch
```

.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i could use this if $old is zero:

```
if [ $old = $z40 ]; then
    old=`$(git rev-list --boundary $newrev --not --all | sed -n 's/^-//p'`
fi
```

.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand well, you want something like this :

```
while read old new ref; do
    if [[ "${old}" =~ ^0+$ ]]; then
        range="${new}"
    else
        range="${old}..${new}"
    fi
    git log --format=%s "${range}"
done
```

Comment: Well, if range is only $new, it won' t show all the comments.